# pip does not find the cudatoolkit that conda has installed

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, conda

I'm trying to install torch_scatter with pip. However it gives me an error message:

```
      File "/home1/huangjiawei/miniconda3/envs/lin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 404, in build_extensions
        self._check_cuda_version()
      File "/home1/huangjiawei/miniconda3/envs/lin/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 781, in _check_cuda_version
        raise RuntimeError(CUDA_MISMATCH_MESSAGE.format(cuda_str_version, torch.version.cuda))
    RuntimeError:
    The detected CUDA version (9.0) mismatches the version that was used to compile
    PyTorch (11.3). Please make sure to use the same CUDA versions.
```

But i did install cudatoolkit by conda:

```
(lin) huangjiawei@ai-server-2:~/linzhijie_Weakly-supervised-Query-based-Video-Segmentation$ conda list|grep cuda
cudatoolkit               11.3.1               h2bc3f7f_2    defaults
pytorch                   1.10.2          py3.8_cuda11.3_cudnn8.2.0_0    https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/pytorch
pytorch-mutex             1.0                        cuda    https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/anaconda/cloud/pytorch
```

So it seems that pip only detected the cuda version of the sever,but didn't detected the cuda version in my enviroment.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This error is complaining that your system **CUDA compiler** (`nvcc`) version doesn't match. `cudatoolkit` you installed in `conda` is **CUDA runtime**. These two are different components.

To install CUDA compiler, you need to install the CUDA toolkit from NVIDIA